Ffter upgrade Kubuntu to 24.04, boot ends up with tty1. Can't start any gui from there
I used the proposed upgrade to Kubuntu 24.04 from Discover. The whole upgrade process went fine with no issue.
But after restart, I'm stuck with login to tty1 only. Moving to graphics (ctrl+alt+f7) does not work. Trying to log in and sudo startx moves me to a small terminal window and no further access (pc is stuck).
What can I do?

startx should be run as your regular user - not with sudo

ok thanks. Tested but very same result : small terminal window, with PC completely blocked...

Try the following:
Start your computer
Run the following
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt -m install
sudo apt install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
sudo reboot


thanks for the very quick answer !


option "--reconfigure" does not seem available, neither something alike.



for apt update, I got some errors(warnings) : e.g. temp error: impossible to retrieve http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease



finally for kubuntu-desktop install, I also got errors - of course - : impossible to retrieve http;//fr.archive.ubutu.com/ubuntu/pool/...


I probably will need to full reinstall ? :-(

I suspect a reinstall wont' help, it sounds like you are having a network issue.

Try dpkg-reconfigure -a instead?

Really this is a list of things that either fix various problems or do nothing if the problem isn't there.    If any one of these gives an error you need to add the error to your question so that we can suggest further fixes.

It's sudo dpkg --configure -a, typo fixed. Repeat the orders a couple of times. Change the location of your repositories.
